# Users uploaded image and matching an id or taxonomy

Tags: custom-field, images

I have many posts with a unique reference for a custom field [123456], over time I would like an administrator to upload a single image that matches the custom field ie > 123456.jpg

I would then like to use a condition in the loop that says if file exists (123456.jpg) that matches the custom field (123456) then use that image for all posts with that custom field...

I cant use the Media library because the folder structure is chronological, is there another way?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use the media library and either reference the attachment's ID or add a postmeta to the attachment containing your id.

You could even make this a bit easier by using a custom taxonomy instead of custom field. Add your numbers as terms to that taxonomy. Also register the taxonomy to apply to attachments. Then write a bit of code that whenever the post has (a) term(s) in that taxonomy finds the attachments that also have a the same term(s) in that taxonomy. This would even allow you to have both, multiple of your numbers for a post and multiple images per number, leading to all kinds of possible combinations.

Comment: wow that made my head spin, don't understand that without seeing the code

Comment: Sorry, too busy to write it for you. But i'll try to make it a bit clearer...just imagine your custom taxonomy would be the tags. So you add tags capability to attachments (google for `wordpress register taxonomy for object'). Now instead of adding your 'special number' as a custom field, you add it as a tag. Admin then adds the same number as a tag to attachments. The only custom code you need then goes something like this: - fetch tags for post, - for each tag, fetch the attachment(s) with the same tag, - for each found attachment, get the file url. WP has functions for all of that.

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sence, using The taxonomy rather than a custom field, having given it more thought I'm not actually sure I've thought of the best solution. 20 post might need to use the same image but I want the user to upload 1 image and the posts to use it if it exists without the user having to go into each post and add the taxonomy.

Comment: @erichmond Well, if you add the taxonomy or a custom field is the same in the end, isn't it. You'll have to write some code to do it automatically in either case.